# How to know if Top level site is created or not

Tags: 2007

I am new to SharePoint. In my office somebody has developed a portal using MOSS 2007 and he was a newbie too..I am receiving 404 connection close error more often so googled and got the information that perhaps we dont have site collection (top level) site created.

How to check if we have top level site created or not.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the browser you could:

Central Admin -> Application Management -> SharePoint Site Management -> Site Collection List

Then choose the web application, and look for the root site ('/')

Comment: oops, you beat me to it, while I was making the screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

Through the GUI:

- Go to Central administration site
- Under Application management tab, click Site Collection List:

[image]

- Search for the '/' root site collection present

Through the code (consider you created a console app):

```
if (!SPSite.Exists("http://yoursite/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Site collection does not exist!");
}
```

Btw, 404 is not always means, that you don't have your site collection created. This could be due to some errors (you should look in your SharePoint logs in this case).

Comment: I am facing this error quite often. HTTP/1.1 404 Connection: close Date: Wed, 04 May 2011 04:57:41 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6219 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET...I am clueless what is causing this error..sometimes it works fine sometimes the above error comes..plz help

Comment: Please, check your SharePoint logs to find out what exactly the error is. You can find them in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS`, you will need most recent file. For this purpose you can also use a log viewer, for example, http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Comment: Thanks I am going to get a hold on the log files to investigate. Will get back once I am done. In the mean time thanks to everyone for valuable comments.